# Unable to access MailCatcher from other machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using MailCatcher on rails project on my local machine and it is as usual using localhost: 1080 port. Now i would like to test mail layout on IE6 so i tried to access it from other windows machine (with machineip:1080) but i am not able to access MailCatcher...

I tried accessing site form windows machine which is on port 3000 is accessible. Is there any restriction MailCatcher has ? Or does anybody faced this issue before ?

Answer (score 14):

Quit Mailcatcher and try running it with the following options:

```
mailcatcher --http-ip=0.0.0.0
```

https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher/issues/51

Comment: This didn't work for me - I had to put the actual IP of the machine. Then it worked fine.

Comment: Between your answer and @James's comment, was able to get this to work. Used something like `mailcatcher --http-ip=1.2.3.4`, then navigated to http://1.2.3.4:1080 from the other computer.

Comment: I accidentally discovered something quite wonderful about the answer. If you issue that syntax, you can continue to use `localhost:1080` on your host's browser and also navigate to the host's IP address from another workstation.